# How to merge list of dicts based on dict attribute uniquely

Tags: python, django

I have a two Django Querysets that I want to merge based on its date atrribute. Well it is not really Django question, but I try to explain as clearly as I can.
I need to group entries based on two data attributes. Lets say I have a model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

Now I need to group these entries by month (how many users started on May 2010 etc):

```
truncate_start_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'start_date')
report_start = User.objects.exclude(start_date__isnull=True)\
    .extra({'month': truncate_start_date}).values('month')\
    .annotate(start_count=Count('pk')).order_by('-month')
```

and I have same query for `end_date`:

```
truncate_end_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'end_date')
report_end = Employee.objects.exclude(end_date__isnull=True)\
   .extra({'month': truncate_end_date}).values('month')\
   .annotate(end_count=Count('pk')).order_by('-month')
```

Now this is what `report_start` looks like:

```
[{'start_count': 33, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, 
{'start_count': 79, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, 
{'start_count': 72, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)},
... ]
```

Now, how do I merge these two lists of dicts to one based on `month`? I tried `chain`, but there were duplicate `month` records.
I want to get:

```
[{'start_count': 33, 'end_count': None, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, 
{'start_count': 79, 'end_count': 2, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, 
{'start_count': 72, 'end_count': 8, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)},
... ]
```

What I was able to come up with was to change it to dict and then back to list of dicts. But I believe this is not very elegant solution and there must be a better way to write this pythonic way.
Any ideas? Here is my ugly code:

```
d = dict()
for end in report_end:
    d[end['month']] = {"end_count": end['end_count']}
for start in report_start:
    if start['month'] in d.keys():
        d[start['month']]["start_count"] = start['start_count']
    else:
        d[start['month']] = {"start_count": start['start_count']}
result = []
for key, i in d.items():
    result.append({'month': key,
                   'start_count': i['start_count'] if 'start_count' in i.keys() else None,
                   'end_count': i['end_count'] if 'end_count' in i.keys() else None})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime` is hashable, so you can store it as a key to a `dict` and merge easily. Here is a bit terser solution using `itemgetter`. This assumes that your timestamps are unique within each list of `dict`s.

```
from operator import itemgetter
import datetime


starts = [
{'start_count': 33, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 0, 0)}, 
{'start_count': 79, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 1, 0, 0)}, 
{'start_count': 72, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 1, 0, 0)}
]

# dummy data
ends = [
{'end_count': 122, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 0, 0)}, 
{'end_count': 213, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 1, 0, 0)}, 
{'end_count': 121, 'month': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 1, 0, 0)}
]


starts = dict(map(itemgetter('month', 'start_count'), starts))
ends = dict(map(itemgetter('month', 'end_count'), ends))


joined = [{'month': m, 'start_count': s,  'end_count': ends.get(m, None)}
    for m, s in starts.items()]
```

Comment: nice solution. What if there is a `month` in ends that is not present in starts? Will it be in joined list?

Comment: No, you can modify as follows: take union of month keys, iterate through those in list comprehension and use .get on starts.

Comment: ok, thanks. I thought this would be easy to write with some itertools functions in lower number of lines, but this is also good!